# How can I run different XFCE sessions for the same user?

Tags: xfce, session

I like to have two (or more) different XFCE sessions for one user which have differences in autostart programs, panel design and others.
Is it possible to make that, are there profiles for XFCE? (For LXDE, there are)
How can I set / switch between different profiles?

Comment: You mean like named sessions you'd choose on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether the settings that you want are user- or session-specific. You can try and see.

In Settings Manager - Sessions and Startup - General: check 'Display chooser on login' so as to be prompted **after login** to chose between your Xfce sessions. To save a certain session, you can save it manually ( Settings Manager - Sessions and Startup - Session) or check 'Automatically save session on logout" (Settings Manager - Sessions and Startup - General).

Comment: If, before login, one choses a non-Xfce session or a different username, the Xfce sessions referred to above would not be accessible at that point.

Comment: thanks, works partly: startup programs are separate for the different sessions, but unfortunately, panel settings are the same for all sessions. is there are trick to have different panel settings per session?